# I want to access Notes from Salesforce I am getting the response in from of url how to get my actual data from it?

Tags: soql, rest-api, python

SOQL QUERY `-cn = "SELECT Title,Content FROM ContentNote"`

OUTPUT OF Content:/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/ContentNote/0692x000000WFDAAA4/Content

Comment: You can try to make a call to the following URI. It will return you content of note

Comment: You asked the same question and received an answer yesterday. Please don't repost identical questions. If you need to refine your original question, please edit it; if you have a new question, open a new post.